# Problem about vanishing determinant of a matrix with NSolve

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra, polynomials

When I try to solve my [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260852/plot-curves-or-regions-according-to-zero-determinant-of-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment649649_260852) according to @DanielLichtblau's comments, I encountered another issue, with which I have been struggling for a whole night.

Taking a matrix for example,

```
mat[a_, b_, c_, k_] = {{Cos[a*k], f^3 + 2, -I*f + k/4}, {0, b*Sin[a*k], f}, {1/f^2, (k^2 - 1)/c, k*Cos[a*k]}};
```

where `a`, `b`, `c` and `k` are all real numbers, while `f` is a complex variable

Defining its determinant with a given parameter `c=1`

```
det[a_, b_, k_] := Det[mat[a, b, 1, k]]
```

Because I need the determinant to be zero, taking its numerator should be enough. Also, I assign values to the remaining parameters (`a`, `b`, `k`).

```
fexpr = Numerator[det[1, 1, 0.1]]
```

In view of the variable `f` in the matrix being complex-valued, expanding the numerator and making explicit replacement of its real and imaginary parts

```
polys = ComplexExpand[ReIm[fexpr], f] /. Re[f] -> ref /. Im[f] -> imf
```

Solving for the real and imaginary parts of `f` that make the numerator of the determinant vanishing

```
NSolve[polys, {imf, ref}, Reals]
```

Here the constraint of `Reals` was used since both `imf` and `ref` are real-valued, we only need the real-valued solutions. But, it reports an error which appears to relate to the `Reals` constraint.

> > NSolve::nddc: The system (-0.00249584+0. I)-0.0998334 imf-0.00988384 imf^2+1. imf^4+2. ref-2.95516 imf^2 ref+0.00988384 ref^2-6. imf^2 ref^2+0.985054 ref^3+1. ref^4==0&&(0. +0. I)+<<7>>+2.95516 imf ref^2+4. imf ref^3==0 contains a nonreal constant -0.00249584+0. I. With the domain [DoubleStruckCapitalR] specified, all constants should be real.

Strangely, if I try a slightly modified `polys1`

```
polys1 = {-0.1 - 0.1*imf - 0.01*imf^2 + 1.1*imf^4 + 2.01*ref - 
3.9*imf^2 ref + 0.01*ref^2 - 6.1*imf^2 ref^2 + 0.98*ref^3 + 
1.01*ref^4, 0.01 + 2.01*imf - 0.985*imf^3 + 0.02*imf ref - 4.01*imf^3 ref + 2.955*imf ref^2 + 4*imf ref^3};
```

It turns to work well with `NSolve`

```
NSolve[polys1, {imf, ref}, Reals]

(*{{imf -> 0.00113843, ref -> -1.68558}, {imf -> 1.05537, ref -> 0.278329}, {imf -> -1.03992, ref -> 0.310137}, {imf -> -0.00495377, ref -> 0.0494334}}*)
```

Can anyone please help with this. Thank you very much!

**Update (Dec22)**

I am trying to combine @Bob's answer into a loop but the modified code always gave many errors. I did slight modifications, which can give correct results without looping. Could you give any suggestion?

```
det[a_, b_, k_] = With[{a = a, b = b, k = k}, Det[mat[a, b, 1, k]]];

CurvePoints = {};

fr[k_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := Module[{sol, solrAbs, fexpr}, 
fexpr = Numerator[ComplexExpand[det[a, b, k], {f}]] /. f -> fre + I*fim;
sol = {f -> fre + I*fim} /. NSolve[Thread[(ReIm[fexpr] // ComplexExpand) == 0], {fre, fim}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
solrAbs = Abs[Re@sol[[All, 1, 2]]];
Table[If[solrAbs[[n]] < 0.35,
AppendTo[CurvePoints, {k, a, b} -> sol[[n, 1, 2]]]; 
fr[k, a, b] = {k, a, b, sol[[n, 1, 2]]}, Sequence[]], {n, 1, Length[sol]}]]
```

This is the loop with a temporary monitor

```
pts = Monitor[Table[fr[k, a, b], {a, 0, 1, 0.5}, {b, 0, 1, 0.5}, {k, 0, 0.1, 0.1}], {k, a, b, s}];
```

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical solution? If not what are the values of parameter `a,b,k`?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I am looking for numerical solutions. Please see my update.

Comment: Why do you not simply write: `Solve[fexpr == 0, f]` ?

Comment: @DanielHuber ah! The reason is that I need to handle the real and imaginary parts of `f` separately in my real problem. Please see my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/260852/plot-curves-or-regions-according-to-zero-determinant-of-a-matrix?noredirect=1#comment649649_260852) and discussion therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat[a_, b_, c_, 
   k_] = {{Cos[a*k], f^3 + 2, -I*f + k/4}, {0, b*Sin[a*k], 
    f}, {1/f^2, (k^2 - 1)/c, k*Cos[a*k]}};

det[a_, b_, k_] = 
  ComplexExpand[Det[mat[a, b, 1, k]], {f}] // 
   FullSimplify;

fexpr = Numerator[det[1, 1, 1/10]] /. 
  f -> fre + I*fim;

sol = {f -> fre + I*fim} /. 
   NSolve[
    Thread[(ReIm[fexpr] // ComplexExpand // 
     FullSimplify) == 0], {fre,
      fim}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20] // N

(* {{f -> 0.33036 + 1.04213 I}, 
    {f -> -1.68481 - 0.0191733 I}, 
    {f -> 0.368153 - 1.02289 I}, 
    {f -> 0.00124481 - 0.0000621358 I}} *)

det[1, 1, 1/10] /. sol

(* {-9.83382*10^-17 - 1.82962*10^-16 I, 
     4.4498*10^-19 + 1.95483*10^-17 I,
     5.98657*10^-17 + 7.23935*10^-17 I, 
     1.73762*10^-15 - 1.7362*10^-14 I} *)
```

**EDIT:** For your revised question. The imaginary terms that were occurring in the `NSolve` were artifacts from the use of machine precision.

```
mat[a_, b_, c_, 
   k_] = {{Cos[a*k], f^3 + 2, -I*f + k/4}, {0, b*Sin[a*k], 
    f}, {1/f^2, (k^2 - 1)/c, k*Cos[a*k]}};

det[a_, b_, k_] = With[{a = a, b = b, k = k}, Det[mat[a, b, 1, k]]];

CurvePoints = {};

fr[k_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 Module[{sol, solrAbs, fexpr}, 
  fexpr = Numerator[FullSimplify[
      ComplexExpand[det @@ SetPrecision[{a, b, k}, 35], {f}]]] /. 
    f -> fre + I*fim;
  sol = {f -> fre + I*fim} /. NSolve[
     Thread[(ReIm[fexpr] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify) == 0], 
     {fre, fim}, Reals, WorkingPrecision -> 20];
  solrAbs = Abs[Re@sol[[All, 1, 2]]];
  Table[If[solrAbs[[n]] < 7/20, 
    AppendTo[CurvePoints, {k, a, b} -> sol[[n, 1, 2]]];
    fr[k, a, b] = {k, a, b, sol[[n, 1, 2]]}, Sequence[]],
   {n, 1, Length[sol]}]]

Off[NSolve::precw]

pts = Monitor[
   Table[fr[k, a, b], {a, 0, 1, 1/2}, {b, 0, 1, 1/2}, 
     {k, 0, 1/10, 1/10}], {k, a, b, s}];
```

The format of the `CurvePoints` is unusual

```
CurvePoints[[1]]

(* {0, 0, 0} -> 0.3478103847799310287 + 1.0288522541366924034  I *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I am trying to modify your code into a loop but the modified code always gave errors. I did some slight modifications only, which can give the same result as yours without looping. Could you give some suggestion?

Comment: impressive! It now works at least. But checking `pts`, it is found some elements are something like `If[Re[{f -> I fim + fre}[[All, 1, 2]]]...]` instead of numeric. Also each of the unevaluated element seems to correspond to a warning of _Part specification {f->I\ fim+fre}[[All,1,2]] is longer than depth of object_. Why `pts` include these non-numeric elements? Does it mean `NSolve` fail to find a solution for the corresponding parameter values. If this is the case, is there any way to remove them?

Comment: I have checked with the parameter values of the non-numeric elements and found that the `sol`s exist actually with those parameter values ...

Comment: I do not see any error messages nor any `If` statements in `pts`. There are `Null` from the `Sequence[]`. Change `Sequence[]` to `Nothing` to remove the `Null`

Comment: `Thread[(ReIm[fexpr]  // FullSimplify) == 0]` by itself does not ensure that all of the complex terms have been cancelled out. The `ComplexExpand` helps to ensure that the necessary transformations are performed to eliminate any complex representations. If any complex representations remain, the `NSolve` will fail since its domain is restricted to `Reals`

Comment: Thank you, I just understand the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Try `NMinimize`

```
mat[a_, b_, c_,k_] := {{Cos[a*k], f^3 + 2, -I*f + k/4}, {0, b*Sin[a*k],f}, {1/f^2, (k^2 - 1)/c, k*Cos[a*k]}}
/. f -> fre + I fim;
det=Det[mat[1, 1, 1, 1/10]] // Simplify
eqn = Thread[ComplexExpand[ReIm[det]] == 0]
```

`NMinimize` evaluates a minimum solution which fullfills the equations

```
sol=NMinimize[{fre^2 + fim^2, eqn}, {fre, fim}]
(*{1.19517, {fre -> 0.33036, fim -> 1.04213}}*)

eqn /. Equal -> Subtract /. sol[[2]]
(*{2.14508*10^-9, -4.62391*10^-8}*)
```

It seems to be a unique solution

```
Show[{ContourPlot[Evaluate [eqn], {fre, -.020, 1   }, {fim, 0, 1.5 }]  ,
Graphics[Point[{fre,fim}/. sol[[2]]]]}]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

**addendum**

`NSolve`works too inside a given parameter range:

```
NSolve[{eqn, 0 < fre < 2, 0 < fim < 2} // Flatten, {fre, fim}]
(*{{fre -> 0.33036, fim -> 1.04213}}*)
```

Comment: It's only necessary if the solution isn't unique.

Comment: in your case also `NMinimize[{1, eqn}, {fre, fim}]`  or `NMinimize[{ #.#&[eqn/.Equal->Subtract]}, {fre, fim}]`  give the same result!

Comment: What means "What is the rationale?"?

Comment: now I understand your method, but I think Bob's method is more suitable for my problem. Thank you again!